# Show that for discrete random variable $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{P_W(n+1)}{P_W(n)} <\infty$

Tags: probability

Suppose that $W$ is a discrete random variable supported on $\mathbb{N}$. Let $P_W$ denote the pmf of $W$. Moreover, assume that $P_W(n)>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Question: Can we show that 
\begin{align}
\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \frac{P_W(n+1)}{P_W(n)} <\infty 
\end{align}

**My thinking:**  I think we have to argue via a contradiction argument.   Suppose that the above is not true. I also think we have to use subsequence since we are working with supremum.

That is there exists a subsequence $n_{k_m}$ such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{m \to \infty } \frac{P_W(n_{k_m}+1)}{P_W(n_{k_m})}=\infty 
\end{align}

Now if this true, then there exists some $m^*$  such that for all $m>m^*$
\begin{align}
\frac{P_W(n_{k_m}+1)}{P_W(n_{k_m})} >2
\end{align} 
or equivalently 
\begin{align}
P_W(n_{k_m}+1) \ge P_W(n_{k_m}) 2
\end{align} 
Now by inducition, for every $N$ we have that
\begin{align}
P_W(n_{k_{m+N}}+1) \ge P_W(n_{k_m}) 2^N
\end{align} 
Therefore, there exists some $N$ such that  $P_W(n_{k_{m+N}}+1)>1$.  This, however, violates the property that  pmf is bounded by one.

**Question:**  Is this a correct argument?

Comment: Your problem is that you have $P(n_{k_m} + 1)$ and not $P(n_{k_{m+1}})$ so your induction does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any further assumption this is not true.

Here is a counterexample:

Take any probability measure $P$ on $\Bbb{N}$ then we have $$\sum_{n \in\Bbb{N}} P(n) = 1$$

Now define a new measure by $$\tilde{P}(n) = \begin{cases} \frac{P(n)}{n} & \text{for n odd} \\ P(n-1) & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and with $$c:= \sum_{n \in\Bbb{N}} \tilde{P}(n) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \frac{P(n)}{n} + \sum_{n \in\Bbb{N}} P(n) \le 2$$

we get a new probability measure $Q$ on $\Bbb{N}$ by $$Q := \frac{\tilde{P}}{c}$$ hence we can assume that Q is induced by a discrete random variable.

But for $n$ odd we get for $Q$: $$\frac{Q(n+1)}{Q(n)} = \frac{P(n)}{\frac{P(n)}{n}} = n$$ hence $$\sup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} \frac{Q(n+1)}{Q(n)} = +\infty$$

Comment: Thank you very much for a counterexample and clarifying why where my proof breaks down.  I am now very curies what are some nontrivial assumptions that we can make that would make this work?

Comment: The easiest assumption would be that P(n) is decreasing in $n$. What you are asking is actually the same argument as for the ratio test for series (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test ) where  (with $$a_n = \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}$$) the series may converge if $$\liminf a_n \le 1 \le \limsup a_n$$. You are asking for a bound of $\limsup a_n$ but tbh I don't see any conditions on $W$ which can make this work except *assuming* the expresssion is finite or some stricter conditions which make it hold directly (like monotonicity above).

Comment: What if we look at the root test.  What I mean is that if we show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_{n}^{ \frac{1}{n} }$? Wouldn't his imply that  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_{n}}<\infty$?

Comment: Yes, if you have $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} p_n^\frac{1}{n} < +\infty$$ this would imply $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} < \infty$$ and so $$\sup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} < \infty$$. But as said before, this is just one stricter condition which make your initial statement hold directly. 
Why do you need to assume a stronger condition like $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} p_n^\frac{1}{n} < +\infty$$ and not assume $$\sup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} < \infty$$ directly? Otherwise you restrict your distributions unnecessarily.

Comment: Quick question. Can you explain to me why $\limsup  p_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is a stricter condition that the ratio one?

Comment: Another question. Don't we always have that $\limsup  p_n^{\frac{1}{n}}<\infty$?   Just bound $p_n<1$ and the limsup is bounded by $1$.

Comment: I was wrong with the relation. The root test is more strict then the ratio test (that means: It can give you a result of convergence if the other don't) but that means the relation is the other way around, so it holds $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{p_n} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} \quad (*)$$ and indeed we always have $$\limsup  p_n^{\frac{1}{n}}\le 1$$ but this does not help here because of $(*)$.
A prove of $(*)$ can be found e.g. in the german wikipedia https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wurzelkriterium#Das_Wurzelkriterium_ist_sch%C3%A4rfer_als_das_Quotientenkriterium

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this.